# Spacy v3 DocBin unable to save train.spacy bytes object is too large

Tags: python-3.x, named-entity-recognition, spacy-3, spacy-transformers

I want to train large data in spacy v3.0+

There are 8000000 data tokens count
i made 1000000  each chunk and finally murge vai DocBin python code but getting error

```
import os
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import DocBin
from tqdm import tqdm
from spacy.util import filter_spans

merged_doc_bin = DocBin()

fiels = [
    "G:\\success-demo\\product_ner\\test\\train3.spacy",# 3000000 tokens here
    "G:\\success-demo\\product_ner\\test\\train1.spacy", # 3000000 tokens here
    "G:\\success-demo\\product_ner\\test\\train2.spacy", # 2000000 tokens here
]


for filename in fiels:
    doc_bin = DocBin().from_disk(filename)
    merged_doc_bin.merge(doc_bin)


merged_doc_bin.to_disk("G:\\success-demo\\product_ner\\test\\final\\murge.spacy")
```

unable to save vai to_disk

any other way to do this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation due to msgpack, where a single file can't be larger than 2GB.

You don't need to merge these files, though. You can provide a directory rather than a single `.spacy` file for `spacy train`:

```
spacy train config.cfg --paths.train train/ --paths.dev dev/
```

It will recursively load all `.spacy` files in the directory.

Comment: Thank you aab 
I want to detect product metadata like product brand subbrabd etc and it should be matched from input string detect brand subbrabd so NER is good for this right ?

Note : input string the possition of brand and subbrabd is not fixed any places in string it 

The amount of data is too lage otherwise may be used entity_ruler in spacy 

abb any pipline or module can i use this kind of training 


Thank you @abb